# nginx proxy websocket to multi nodes

Tags: nginx, proxy, websocket, socket.io

I use nginx as proxy server, backend are socketio services. Follow the [document](http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/) ,  nginx configuration.

```
upstream socketio {
    ip_hash;
    server server1:3000;
    server server1:3001;
    server server2:3100;
    server server2:3101;
}
```

But for this configuration, same client request always proxy to same backend server.

If want same server request proxy to different backend server, have tried [hash directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#hash) but doesn't work

```
upstream socketio {
    hash "${remote_addr}${remote_port}";
```

Any solution?

Comment: What's wrong with default round-robin? Just remove `ip_hash`.

Comment: @AlexeyTen  refer to http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/,  the ip_hash instruction that indicates the connections will be sticky. If remove ip_hash, client request will be failed.

Comment: But the meaning of "sticky" is always send client to the same backend. Thus I can't understand what do you want.

Comment: @AlexeyTen I don't know, if miss ip_hash, client will disconnect immediately

Comment: @AlexeyTen I just want to know, use nginx to proxy socketio server. If possible proxy different request from same client to different socketio server. for example same client ip + same client port  request proxy to same socketio server